# Writing to an online Mysql database via ODBC

Tags: mysql

I have multiple shops (a few hundred) and they all need to write an online Mysql database, and at about the same time. The program I have has been written in VB6 and it is currently updating the database successfully (via ODBC), although it is only updating three stores at the moment. The plan for the near future is to have all the other stores update to the same Mysql database.

Will Mysql be able to handle all these stores updating it at the same time using ODBC or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you run a load test and find out? It's impossible for anyone to know about the specific behavior of your setup under load, and that those stores actually do when they update the database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of running into problems caused by too many concurrent connections it depends very much on the platform your database is running on.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

Creating a test environment to stress test your database would be a sensible way for you find out if it is going to be up to it.

If your database cannot cope with the load, there are many scalable cloud based resources around now which can easily be expanded to cope with higher load. Google Cloud, Windows Azure or Amazon may be worth a look.